# in-mobi or admob which is better?

Tags: android, admob, ads, inmobi

I am developing an android application that will conduct a test. This test will be a 3 hours long test. I have thought to include ads in my application. So please suggest me:

1) inmobi or admob? which one is better as I am an Indian resident? or any other ad provider?
2) as the test will be 3 hours long so can i reload the ads after every 3 minutes? Is it a good practice? If yes, then how this can be achieved?

I am very new to this monitization thing. So please explain clearly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pricing and/or legal stuff rather than any programming problem.

Comment: I apologise if i am mistaken but i need programming help too.

Comment: But it is the only place where that question could be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is better for Indian residents. But more important is where you game is more popular. Admob has geographically widest fill rate. In-mobi will offer higher eCPM in certain markets like USA. In-Mobi may give 0% fill rate in east Europe or India or China.

Better is to have both networks. Check if banner is available and show at least from one network.

If your app would be able to connect to your server then you would be able to tell which network show based on some rule like IP->Country -> network eCPM in that country and fill rate.